# what does memory aligned at 64 mean? is it that the address is 64 bytes apart?

Tags: c, assembly, memory-address

```
unsigned long long loc[8] __attribute__((aligned(64)))
```

Could someone explain what attribute here does?

Also what would be the address of `loc[1]` be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `unsigned long long` array will be aligned on a 64-byte boundary. `loc[1]` will be at `<base address> + sizeof(unsigned long long)` since `aligned` only controls the base address of the structure.